# Dash Python - How to make the x-axis display only integers in bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am a newbie to Dash Framework and Plotly. I am trying to plot a bar chart. I want the x-axis to display only integral values . Here's the code of the dash core component:-[image: x-axis]

```
 dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart1', figure=px.bar(data_frame=df,
                                                     x='x', y='y',))
```

How do I display only integral values in x-axis like 17,18,19 ? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, you can try `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`.

Comment: Hey hoa! What is fig here? I read the documentation of plotly but I couldn't figure out how to do it in Dash. Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: Maybe you can do something like that:
`fig = px.bar(data_frame=df,x='x',y='y')
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`

and then change `dcc.Graph to:  dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart1', figure=fig))`